# Is there a way to get (*pointer)[ index ] functionality from something more terse?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, smart-pointers, subscript-operator

I have a class to represent a one dimensional spectrum. The underlying datatype is a simple array of floats. To manipulate elements of the spectrum I overloaded the subscript operators as follows:

```
class OneDSpectrum
{
public:
    ...
    float& operator[](int index);
    const float& operator[](int index) const;
    ...
private:
    int numChannels;
    float* histogram;
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, almost all uses of this class are as pointers so I have the somewhat annoying `(*pointerToSpectrum)[ index ]` notation to deal with now.

I had two initial ideas:

My first idea was to overload the subscript operator for `OneDSpectrum*`, but that just looks like a basket full of potential issues and trouble.

My second idea was to make some sort of custom smart pointer for OneDSpectrums.

So my question is this:  *Is it reasonable to do `SmartPointerToSpectrum[ index ]` to get `(*pointerToSpectrum)[ index ]` functionality? Or should I just deal with using a lot of `(*pointerToSpectrum)[ index ]`?*

Comment: Something simpler might be better: create `at` functions that do the same job and write `ptr->at(idx)`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The wording of the initial question was poorly thought out, as I wrote it it is certainly a very very bad idea. Also, I missed the previous question, do you know if it is possible for me to delete this question without removing the reputation that FredOverflow got from a decent answer?

Comment: @JamesMatta: Why do you want to delete it, and Fred's content along with it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, because, on reexamination, it was a silly question and there is similar question I missed that basically gave the same answer. You have a point though. I have tried to change the question 'title' to be less retarded in phrasing so that bit of shame is gone.

Comment: @JamesMatta: Lol okay. Good reason. No there's no way to delete it without nuking Fred's rep, unless you wait six months beforehand.

Comment: FWIW I think this is a perfectly good question, even if the thing you are trying to do in it is not.

Comment: Ah well, then it shall stay up.

Comment: Well, in its current form th dupe isn't a dupe anymore :-/

Comment: @rubenvb Yeah, I actually was editing it not because of the duplication issue but because if it was going to stay up I did not want quite such a silly question 'on permanent record' as it were. Sorry about that.

Comment: @James don't worry. SO has seen worse than your arguably "silly" question. And thanks for taking the time to increase the quality of your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately, almost all uses of this class are as pointers

Have you considered using references instead?

```
void foo(OneDSpectrum* a, OneDSpectrum& b)
{
    (*a)[0] = 42;
    b[0] = 97;
}

int main()
{
    OneDSpectrum x;
    OneDSpectrum y;
    foo(&x, y);
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that they are all created on the fly. While the end result the user looks at is 1 spectrum the background subtraction process could generate potentially hundreds of these things when performing the queries. Although, thinking about it, because of the way all the queries are encapsulated in tasks for worker threads it might be workable... I will have to think some more. Thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider `pointerToSpectrum->get(index)`?